# Is there a return keyword in bash?

Tags: git, bash

In the code below I need a return keyword in the first if statement.  I need to exit the function after the echo.b

```
push() {
  a=$1
  b=$2
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
     echo "Enter git shortname for first argument"
  fi

  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
      b=$(timestamp)
  fi
  git add -A .
  git commit -m $b
  git push $a
  echo "push() completed."
}
```

**Research**

Google pulls up [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419952/difference-between-return-and-exit-in-bash-functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
push() {
  local a="$1" b="$2" #don't overwrite global variables
  [ "$#" -eq 0 ] && { 
    1>&2 echo "Enter git shortname for first argument" #stderr
    return 64 #EX_USAGE=64
  }
  : "${b:=`timestamp`}" #default value
  git add -A .
  git commit -m "$b"  #always quote variables, unless you have a good reason not to
  git push "$a"
  1>&2 echo "push() completed."
}
```

The above should run in `dash` as well as `bash`, if case you want to make use of the faster startup time.

## Why quote?

If you don't quote, variables will get split on characters present in `$IFS`, which by default is the **space**, the **newline**, and the **tab** character. Also, **asterisks** within the contents of unquoted variables are **glob**-expanded. Usually, you want neither the splitting nor the glob expansion, and you can unsubscribe from this behavior by double quoting your variable.

I think it's a good practice to quote by default, and comment the cases when you don't quote because you *really* want the splitting or the globbing there.

(`Bash` doesn't split or glob-expand in assignments so `local a=$1` is safe in `bash`, however other shells (most prominently `dash`) do. `a="$1"` is ultra-safe, consistent with how variables behave elsewhere, and quite portable among shells.)

Comment: I added the `local` as I'v heard about global pollution in JS before it had strict mode ... but why should I quote variables.  What does that do ?

Comment: @cadegalt Thanks for accepting the answer. I've added an explanation on why quoting is a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

BASH does have `return` but you may not need it in your function. You can use:

```
push() {
  a="${1?Enter git shortname for first argument}"

  [[ $# -eq 1 ]] && b=$(timestamp)
  b=$2

  git add -A .
  git commit -m $b
  git push $a
  echo "push() completed."
}
```

`a="${1?Enter git shortname for first argument}"` will automatically return from function with given error message if you don't pass any argument to it.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite it such that it always exits at the bottom. Use nested if constructs so yo don't have to bail out in the middle.

Comment: an else statement is one way to do this

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with `bash`'s `return` statement?

```
push() {
  a=$1
  b=$2
  if [ $# -eq 0 ]
  then
     echo "Enter git shortname for first argument"
     return
  fi

  if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
      b=$(timestamp)
  fi
  git add -A .
  git commit -m $b
  git push $a
  echo "push() completed."
}
```