# 'exit' Command inside a function causing host screen window to close

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

**Edit: If I can use `return` instead, what about functions that use `set -e`?**

I run screen on my Linux VM in order to have multiple terminals that I can disconnect from and return to when I want.

I'm having issues with running bash commands that use functions that either directly call `exit` or have `set -e` in them - they cause the screen terminal to close and kick me out to another one of my screen terminals.

Is there a way to get screen to stop responding to `exit` calls, or perhaps make it aware that the `exit` is purely for the return value of the function that's using it?

The offending function:

```
function unpackdb() {
  cd $DB_LOCATION
  mkdir -p downloads
  cd downloads
  db_file_name=$(ls -t *.tar.gz 2> /dev/null | head -1)
  if [ -n "$db_file_name" ] ; then
    tar xf $db_file_name -C ../data
    echo "Latest file (${db_file_name}) restored in to ${pwd}/../data"
  else
    echo "Could not find a .tar.gz in ${pwd}, if you don't care use command 'startdb'"
    exit 1
  fi
}
```

Comment: I understand the the function is defined in current shell environment. Replace exit with **return** and it will do the trick.

Comment: @Joe: See: [Difference between return and exit in BASH functions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4419952/3776858)

Comment: `function exit() { echo "no exit"; }`

Comment: @AlexWeitz Not "terminal". "Shell instance"/"Shell session". The terminal is the program giving you the window and running the shell.

Comment: You can also open a new shell session inside your original session by writing "bash" before running the command. You'll then be kicked out to your previous shell session
@EtanReisner thanks, fixed.

Comment: If I can use `return` instead, what about functions that use `set -e`?

Comment: Suspicion...  given that **unpackdb()** function quoted above erroneously used **exit 1** (instead of **return 1**), do these other functions even need a `set -e`?  Maybe a code snippet using `set -e` would help clarify things.

Comment: The issue was that `set -e` is very useful, however you can't use it whilst running the function in the current shell of the screen terminal.