# Need help understanding a strange bashrc expression

Tags: bash

The first thing in my bashrc file is this expression:

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac
```

Can somebody explain what this means?

all these symbols make it really hard to google, and there is no Haskell "hoogle" equivalent for bash so I can search for symbol expressions.

The intended behavior seems to be similar to this.

```
nonsourced=0;

# if sourced,
if [[ "$0" == "$BASH_SOURCE" ]]; then
    nonsourced=1;
else
    nonsourced=0;
fi

echo "nonsourced? $nonsourced";


case $- in
    *i*) 
        # this case is entered if "$-" contains "i".
        if [[ "$nonsourced" -eq "0" ]]; then
            echo "1. " "$-";
        fi
        ;; # leave case?
    *) # this case is entered in all other cases.
        if [[ "$nonsourced" -eq "0" ]]; then
            echo "2. " "$-";
            return
        else
            # cannot return from nonsourced, use exit.
            echo "avoided return from nonsourced #2";
            exit 0;
        fi
        ;; # leave case?
esac

echo "3";
```

Comment: `*)` is the "default", an interesting link: http://www.linux.org/threads/case-statement-in-bash-scripts.5602/ (I searched "bash case asterisk")

Comment: You can try symbolhound.com for searching with strings that contain symbols.

Comment: Why do you need to google? Don't you know where the bash manual is located? http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: Isn't it invalid to use return from outside a function? This part of code is outside a function; it might be sourced, but assuming this is wrong.

Comment: You don't need to google anything. Type `man bash` in your shell, keep calm and start reading. Everything is explained there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can somebody explain what this means?

- `$-` The list of options set in the shell at the point of evaluation.

  When a shell (bash) starts it accepts some options:

  LESS=+'/^ *OPTIONS' man bash

  > All  of  the  single-character shell options documented in the description of the set builtin command can be used as options when the shell is invoked. In addition, bash interprets the following options when it is invoked:

  One of such options is `-i`. So calling bash as `bash -i …` should <sup>[a]</sup> trigger that option inside<sup>[a]</sup> the shell.

  <sup>[a] I say **should** as some other conditions are also required to have an effective interactive shell. Also, an interactive shell may be started by simply writing `bash` in a terminal (no `-i` option used)</sup>

  <sup>[b] The way to print some options that have been set is with `echo $-`</sup>
- `*i*) ;;` tests if the string from `$-` contains an `i`, if so, do nothing.
- `*) return;;` On any other value of `$-` return (go out the script<sup>[c]</sup> ).

  <sup>[c] Please [read this answer for return vs. exit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419971/6843677).</sup>

In overall, it does what the comment says:

`# If not running interactively, don't do anything`

Or with a clearer wording:

`# If running interactively, exit`<sup>[d]</sup>.

<sup>[d] It may be more technically correct to use the word `return` instead of `exit`, but the idea is cleaner, I believe.</sup>

Note that there is a quite similar construct with `$PS1` (used in `/etc/bash.bashrc` and repeated in `~/.bashrc` in debian based systems, for example):

```
# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return
```

---

As for the problem of finding symbols:

```
> all these symbols make it really hard to google
```

even if it doesn't cover so many pages, `SymbolHound` may be of help here.

[If we try it](http://symbolhound.com/?q=*i*%29)

we [find this](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html)

Which clearly explains what you are asking.

Comment: @user8017719 Do you know the reason, why symbolhound went down?

Answer (score 2):

See the [documentation for Bash variables](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html):

> `$-`: A hyphen expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set built-in command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i).

The asterisks in the case patterns are wildcards, so essentially the whole case says “if there’s an `i` [as interactive] somewhere in the arguments, go on, otherwise return”.

Comment: how are $- options set/unset? they are not arguments since `echo $-;` script always says hB.

Comment: I think it’s created internally by Bash, that’s probably also why it’s safe to match for the `i` in such a simple way. I tried to find the right part in the source code, but didn’t succeed.

Comment: The return works because it's assuming it is sourced right? return can't work outside sourced contexts/functions and it's not wrapped in a function.

Answer (score 0):

`$-` lists the current shell options.

The two cases are whether the `-i` interactive flag is present anywhere in that list of options.