# What does return mean?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm analyzing a shell script and I'm a little confused with the piece of code bellow.

Can someone explain me what **return;** is doing in this case?

```
if [ -f "$BYPASS_EXISTING_NETWORK_TEST_FILE" ]; then

      dloginfo "Skipping existing network test; mandated by configuration."
      # Consume the file.
      rm -f "$BYPASS_EXISTING_NETWORK_TEST_FILE"
      return;
fi
```

Comment: `help return`   ...

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between return and exit in BASH functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419952/difference-between-return-and-exit-in-bash-functions)

Answer (score 1):

`return` will return a value from the function.

information from `help return`