Login shell does not source .profile in Gitlab CI
I have this Dockerfile:
FROM ubuntu:24.04

COPY setup.sh /opt/

RUN echo 'echo Hello from .profile' >> /root/.profile
RUN echo 'source /opt/setup.sh' >> /root/.profile

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-l"]

The contents of the setup.sh is:
#!/bin/bash

echo "Executing setup script"

say_hello() {
    echo "Hello World!"
}

I would like to use the Docker image tagged with test to run  the following Gitlab CI testcase:
foo:
  image: registry.git.my-domain.com/test
  script:
    - ls /opt
    - say_hello

This test fails. I get the following output:
Using docker image sha256:fff9c67f9 ...
$ ls /opt
setup.sh
$ say_hello
/usr/bin/bash: line 148: say_hello: command not found


It seems that .profile was not sourced, as the say_hello command should be available if it were. Why does this happen? In my Dockerfile, I am setting up a login shell that should execute .profile.

Do I really have to manually source setup.sh in the testcase foo? I would like to avoid this but to provide a Docker container that does it automatically.



The ´return´ makes the execution stop as described here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4419956/6270743  that's why you need to delete the line containing the return. Why do you even need to stop executing the .bashrc? The simplest solution would be to put this line at the end if you really need it

I know that ´return´ makes the execution stop (see my question) and I do not want to stop executing .bashrc. I want it to fully execute. However, it does not as the line at the end of the file is not executed (see expected output). Although I open an interactive shell, the .bashrc still returns too early. I don't understand why is this the case. I can't imagine that deleting the return statement is the only solution....seems more than a hack.

Most paths to running things in Docker don't run a shell at all; for example, docker run --rm registry.git.my-domain.com/test whoami won't print either bashrc line.  Would putting your required setup into an entrypoint wrapper script work better?

I don't think an entrypoint script would work because variables, aliases etc. defined there won't be visible after the script terminates. Similar problems state to put such things into .bashrc. In that case I have the above problem that I cannot manage to start an interactive shell from Gitlab CI.

Sounds like XY problem. What are you trying to achieve?

Yes, this could be. I will rephrase my question.


Why does this happen?

That's simple - it is not running a login shell.

In my Dockerfile, I am setting up a login shell that should execute .profile.

You are setting CMD. Gitlab executes it's own CMD.

Do I really have to manually source setup.sh in the testcase foo?

No, but that is the best solution, is explicit and readable. Usually put in before_script:.

I would like to avoid this but to provide a Docker container that does it automatically.

You can use ENTRYPOINT to set the entrypoint.
You can use BASH_ENV environment variable to inject anything to any bash session. You can set it with ENV.

don't think an entrypoint script would work because variables, aliases etc. defined there won't be visible after the script terminates.

Do not terminate entrypoint. You can export a function in Bash with export -f.

Thank you. BASH_ENV works perfectly fine!
